# How to copy a data structure with two lists containing pointers to same objects, sorted in two different ways?

Tags: sorting, pointers, object, linked-list

The way I wanted to copy the structure is by taking one of the two lists and copy it including the objects to which each node points. The problem is that this way I found myself needing to resort the copied objects in order to create the second list of pointers (by a different order than the first one), and this is obviously not efficient.
I found a way to solve the problem but it just seem inelegant and it makes it a bit harder for me to program other parts of my program, so I would love to hear some more ideas.

The idea I had:
In addition to the information requires, each object would also contain it's place in the second list. When copying the structure we would also create an array of object pointers. The copying would be done by going threw the first list, and copying it and a pointer to each copied object would be placed in the place in the array, at the place fits to the object according to the second list. Than, creating the second list using the array, is easy.

So, are there any different elegant efficient ways to solve it?